# Block UI using jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-blockui

I use jQuery to block ui like this

```
$('#send').click(function() {
       $.blockUI({ message: 
       '<p id="loading"><img src="images/busy.gif" /> processing...</p>'});  
        send();
       $(document).ajaxStop($.unblockUI); 
       setTimeout($.unblockUI, 2000); 

});
```

`send()` does some background processing and sets a response message in #loading tag. After the process is finished I want this message to stay for some seconds so I use the setTimeout but this does not work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script seems to call the `unblockUI` using `ajaxStop` already? Have you tried to remove this line or set your timeout within the `ajaxStop` handler?

**UPDATE**

You could try this:

```
$('#send').click(function() {
    $.blockUI({ message: '<p id="loading"><img src="images/busy.gif" /> processing...</p>'});  
    send();
    $(document).ajaxStop(function(){
        setTimeout($.unblockUI, 2000); 
    }); 
});
```

Comment: but when I remove ajaxStop, the ui is unblocked no matter if the process is finished or not. how do I set the timeout within ajaxStop?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's `delay([time in seconds])` function.
As far as I know, `setTimeout` works on another workflow than the rest of the script.

Comment: Well, you append it to the queue of actions attached to a selector. For example, `$("#div").show().delay(2000).hide();`. The thing is, as I remember, that `delay()` is most suitable for effects; it is not a replacement for `setTimeout()`. Now, I don't know exactly whether it is suitable for what you intend to do or not.